# Is there a way native javasacript way to prevent excessive memory usage without await in loops?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, eslint

I see that ES Lint is discouraging the use of await in loops, but I don't see any other native-language based option to prevent randomly excessive memory usage when the process inside the loop requires a lot of memory.

I understand that this could be prevented with the use of promise queues, but those have to be implemented or imported in a library.

Why are they promoting this kind of reckless use of memory and resources?

If I run all the processes "at once" with `Promise.all()` when each process can consume a highly random amount of memory, and there could be a huge amount of items to process, the script will likely crash, wouldn't it?

Or can you confirm if when using `Promise.all()` javascript will handle the memory properly to ensure that the memory is not exhausted by running all processes at once?

And what if the process opens network connections and have millions of items to process? I can easily hit the maximum network connections of the OS, and would have to put in place more mechanisms to queue those.

Why is it so wrong to use a simple await in a loop? They say the only reasonable reason for using awaits in a loop is when the iterations need information from each other, but just to prevent excessive resource consumption seems reasonable enough to me, isn't it?

Is there an alternative language-native way to run asynchronous heavy processes over a large list of items without risking excessive resource consumption?

Am i misunderstanding the ES Lint recommendations?

Here is the link:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop

Comment: Depending on your use case activate or disable the rule. If you want to execute each "resource heavy task" one by one then your completely fine.. Rules NEVER apply to EVERY use case in life.

Comment: If your processes are resource-heavy maybe look into [worker threads](https://medium.com/@Trott/using-worker-threads-in-node-js-80494136dbb6).

Comment: They recommend these rules, because your use-case is uncommon. I've never seen a frontend code that would crash the client without `await`. They didn't consider excessive resource consumption. The rule is good for 99% of the projects and your project is the 1%.

Comment: await in loops also makes sense if you access a rate limited API for example - simply disable the rule where you know you are using await for a good reason - it even says so in that link you posted!

Comment: It's ok to disable the rule in the case you describe. ESLint doc mentions (without going into the details of what would be the consequences for memory/network usage) [When Not To Use It](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop#when-not-to-use-it)" : _loops may be used to prevent your code from sending an excessive amount of requests in parallel. In such cases it makes sense to use await within a loop and it is recommended to disable the rule via a standard ESLint disable comment._

Comment: it's odd that the eslint page mentions *the parallelization benefits of async/await* ... by definition `await` precludes parallelization - it's a bizarre statement that await has such benefits

Comment: You should consider using pools in your cases, e.g. connection pool, worker pool. This way you can limit the number of concurrent tasks, but you still have the advantages of concurrency. You don't want to send one million HTTP requests at a time but you probably also don't want to await each response, before you send the next request. The pool size is usually configurable and depends on the environment.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the purpose of ES Lint rules, but they sound to me as some kind of best-practice recommendations. But 99% of the time the `await` in loops should scale better than Promise.all() (which is the alternative they suggest). Using pools or queues is of course ideal, but it is also unnecessary complexity in most cases. Is there a forum or something where they discuss the addition of these rules?

Comment: No, in 99% you shouldn't use `await` in a loop. Even in your case, I wouldn't use an `await` in a loop, but a worker pool. In 99% you want to concurrently send the requests. Why should the client wait for work that is done on the server?

Comment: Doesn't a worker pool require more lines of code?, more api calls?, more development work? more documentation? more testing? That just makes your software harder to maintain, when a simple await in a loop can do the job... @jabaa

Comment: You have a very special case. You usually concurrently start all tasks. In your case, you want to manage the resources. An `await` in a for loop is a really bad resource manager.

Comment: You're correct, the await is a bad resource manager, but it's simple, and works natively, which makes the solution cleaner... I really would like to have this discussion in a proper place. Don't these guys have a place for that? or they come up with these rules on their sleep?

Comment: Simple doesn't mean good. Even in your case, `await` in a loop is really bad. You made the example with one million network connections. Let's say you would use `await` in a loop and wait 0.5 seconds per request. That's 500.000 s. You could easily reduce it concurrently sending 100 requests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244639/discussion-between-jacmkno-and-jabaa).

Comment: No, let us not. You have your opinion and I have mine. That's the reason you shouldn't ask opinionated questions.

Comment: Usually I arrive to non-opinionated questions through the discussion of opinionated questions, that get downvoted. That's the cost of learning here. The question I came up with is: "Where is the right place to discuss ES Lint rules?" and I think the answer is here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions

Comment: The question is: _"Is there a way native javasacript way to prevent excessive memory usage without await in loops?"_ The answer is, of course.

Comment: I don't want people explaining how pools, workers, or task queue work, but, you're right, of course there is a way. I posted the other question here in case you want to continue the discussion there: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/discussions/15863